# My read and write string function spits out %%% instead of the 3 characters I put in

Tags: assembly, kernel, nasm, x86-16

So I've begun to write a "kernel" so to say and I'm trying to read a string and print it back to me. The problem comes when I execute it and it just prints 3 of the same char instead of what I wrote on the line.

```
read_string:
    call newline
    mov si, read_attempt
    call print
    call newline
    push bx
    mov ah, 0x03
    int 0x10
    mov dl, 0
    int 0x10
                    ;read 1st char
    mov ah, 0x08
    int 0x10
    mov bl, al
    pop bx
                    ;read 2nd char
    mov ah, 0x03
    int 0x10
    add dl, 1
    int 0x10
    mov ah, 0x08
    int 0x10
    mov bl, al
    pop bx
                    ;read 3rd char
    mov ah, 0x03
    int 0x10
    add dl, 1
    int 0x10
    mov ah, 0x08
    int 0x10
    mov bl, al
    pop bx
                    ;try to write all 3 chars
    call newline
    mov si, write_attempt
    call print
    call newline
    push bx
    mov al, bl
    call printchar
    push bx
    mov al, bl
    call printchar
    push bx
    mov al, bl
    call printchar
    call newline
    mov si, read_write_success
    call print
    call newline
    ret
```

Please keep in mind that everything before the "second sector" was written like 2 months ago and everything after has been written in the past 2 days. I'm also using NASM to assemble the code.

Here is a picture of what it's doing [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVvR8.png)

Comment: I don't think int 10h, ah=08h does what you think it does. I suggest you read about int 10h and then describe in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: doing int 10h and ah=08h should "Read character and attribute at cursor position" and place the char into al so I can do a mov bl, al and push it into a stack for later use

Comment: That's right; what character is at the cursor position? Also, what are the other int 10h calls for?

Comment: The edit invalidated the answer.  If you still have bugs, single-step your code in a debugger.  (e.g. use BOCHS which has a built-in debugger that can debug boot-sector code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing some text on the screen and then are trying to read the first 3 characters of this text from the screen. Right?

It's fine to use BIOS function 08h to this effect but you forget to position the cursor each time!

```
call newline
mov  si, read_attempt
call print
call newline    ;(*)
```

This has just output some text leaving the cursor **below** its first character.
To find out the row you need to use BIOS function 03h and then go up 1 row.
You only need to specify the display page in `BH` once provided you don't use the `BH` register for anything else!
Important: Don't forget to specify the function numbers.

```
mov  bh, 0      ;Select display page 0
mov  ah, 03h    ;BIOS.GetCursor -> CL, CH, DL, DH
int  10h

dec  dh         ;Go 1 row up, Column is at 0 because of (*)
mov  ah, 02h    ;BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h

mov  ah, 08h    ;BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute -> AL, AH
int  10h
push ax         ;Save 1st character on stack
```

No need to re-read the cursor position because the `DL` and `DH` registers still hold the position. Just increment the column in `DL` and set it through BIOS:

```
inc  dl         ;Go 1 column right
mov  ah, 02h    ;BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h

mov  ah, 08h    ;BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute -> AL, AH
int  10h
push ax         ;Save 2nd character on stack
```

Repeat for the 3rd character:

```
inc  dl         ;Go 1 column right
mov  ah, 02h    ;BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h

mov  ah, 08h    ;BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute -> AL, AH
int  10h
push ax         ;Save 3rd character on stack
```

To print use:

```
pop  ax         ;Restore 3rd character
call printchar
pop  ax         ;Restore 2nd character
call printchar
pop  ax         ;Restore 1st character
call printchar
```

---

**Because of how the stack works characters will get displayed in reverse order**.
If the order is important then start reading on the screen at the 3rd character and work towards the beginning.

```
mov  bh, 0      ;Select display page 0
mov  ah, 03h    ;BIOS.GetCursor -> CL, CH, DL, DH
int  10h
 MOV  DL, 2      ;START AT 3RD CHARACTER
dec  dh         ;Go 1 row up
mov  ah, 02h    ;BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h
mov  ah, 08h    ;BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute -> AL, AH
int  10h
push ax         ;Save 3rd character on stack
 DEC  DL         ;GO 1 COLUMN LEFT
mov  ah, 02h    ;BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h
mov  ah, 08h    ;BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute -> AL, AH
int  10h
push ax         ;Save 2nd character on stack
 DEC  DL         ;GO 1 COLUMN LEFT
mov  ah, 02h    ;BIOS.SetCursor
int  10h
mov  ah, 08h    ;BIOS.ReadCharacterAndAttribute -> AL, AH
int  10h
push ax         ;Save 1st character on stack
...
pop  ax         ;Restore 1st character
call printchar
pop  ax         ;Restore 2nd character
call printchar
pop  ax         ;Restore 3rd character
call printchar
```

Comment: The BIOS cursor position is zero-based. The 3rd character therefore is at `DL=2`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using push where you mean pop and vice versa. Push saves a value on the stack and pop retrieves a value from the stack. So the way the code is written, it prints the value in bl three times. It also messes up the return address on the stack. Make sure your pushes and pops are balanced.

Comment: so I reversed the pops and pushes and now it doesnt print anything